# Big O Analysis for Exponential Function

Tags: big-o

For the below function,

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/56lYK.png]

I did

[image]

But I must have did wrong ... answer should be `O(log n)`. I am terrible at Big O ... havent fully understood master theorem which is not taught in school yet. They taught only recursion tree

Comment: About your `is this correct part`: nope.

Comment: This seems to be http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring (Square-And-Multiply)  The complexity is bound to exp, which halves every "step". when you see a decrease by a constant factor per step, it is usually logarithmic complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we suppose that all arithmetic operations are done in O(1) then:
As we see each function call we divide exp on 2. When we reach zero with exp - we done.
How many times we can divide exp on two without reaching zero? That's log exp. So the log exp function calls * O(1) gives log(exp) complexity.
Finding sum of geometric sequence you finding answer to another problem: how many node in complete (where all siblings exist) tree with n leaves:
suppose n = 4:

```
1'
|_1''
  |_1'''
  |_2'''
|_2''
  |_3'''
  |_4'''
```

you are finding count of node in such a tree

Answer (score 1):

The assumptions you make at the beginning of your math is saying that you spend "n" time in the function call `Exp(n)`, "n/2" time in `Exp(n/2)`, "n/4" time in `Exp(n/4)` and so on...

But, actually, you only spend constant `O(1)` time in each function call. So, then you have `log(n)` function calls of constant time. Try running the rest of your math with this starting assumption and see what you get.